# HTML & JSP with Oracle using tomcat

Tags: html, oracle, jsp, tomcat

I have same some jsp file(like login, jsp & regis.jsp which having connection to jdbc:odbc) and also having html files which is related(linked) to jsp file.
My quesion is,
how can I run these files using Apache Tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

Put them into the [standard directory structure for a WAR file](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html), package them up, and deploy the WAR file in Tomcat's `/webapps` directory.

Once you've done that, start Tomcat and invoke your web app in a web browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo
```

if you deploy foo.war.

Comment: Make sure you have the right Oracle JDBC driver JAR (e.g., ojdbc14.jar -- this will depend on what version of Oracle you're using) installed somewhere in your classpath too.  Typically I put this in tomcat/lib/, if i have more than one webapp that uses the driver.

Comment: And the JVM.  14 in this case means JDK 1.4, which is wicked old.  You should only have versions 6 or 7; pick the one that matches your JVM.  And put it in Tomcat /lib directory.  That's the only place that newer versions of Tomcat will find it.